# Can't set custom startButtons and endButtons properties for super-hands reaction components

Tags: aframe, aframe-super-hands

I'm attempting to utilise other button mappings for `super-hands` other than the defaults but I'm hitting trouble. For example, the `abuttonup` and `abuttondown` events for the Oculus Touch with `progressive-controls`.

When I use the following component, or any of the other reaction components, the `grab-end` or `click` events are not registering for custom button mappings.

```
clickable="startButtons: abuttonup; endButtons: abuttondown"
```

When I override the default `startButtons` and `endButtons` in the `super-hands` source, the buttons work as intended.

Many thanks.

Comment: That syntax looks correct; there is an example here: https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component/blob/master/examples/sticky/index.html (live: https://wmurphyrd.github.io/aframe-super-hands-component/examples/sticky/) Can you pick up the bat with trigger or locomote with grip in that example?

Comment: Yes, however when I changed the buttons to `abuttondown` and `abuttonup` in the A-Frame Inspector, the interaction breaks down again.

Answer (score 0):

The mappings I required have now been added to the `aframe-super-hands` library: [Commit 95a3222](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component/pull/118/commits/95a3222049a483be7be7dba5f88eb08798c1168d)